# Vertical alignment in CSS not working as expected

Tags: css

I must have got a brain malfunction because i can't get this simple vertical alignment to work. The code is as follows.

CSS

```
div#topHolder {
    background: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #0000ff;
}

img#title {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ffff00;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="topHolder">
        <img id="title" src="images/file.gif" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Now, you see, one would expect the image to be in the center of the div but instead it's at it's top. Of course no other values for the alignment work neither. For crying out loud, what am i missing?!

Comment: i cannot reproduce your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/tF96R/

Comment: FF, IE Chrome are tested. And actually i pasted in WHOLE my ASPX and CSS files into jFiddle and guess what! The error can't be reproduced! Also, the uploaded version of the code works as supposed. The only change i've made was to get rid of the atrocity called VS2012 and install VS2010. The code is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you read this article, it explains why vertical-align doesn't work as you expect it to.  In general, it's only works with tables (or objects with table styles) and inline objects.  This is as it is defined by the standard.

http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

EDIT:

Something you may find even more interesting is this, add text on either side of the image.

```
<div id="topHolder">
     xx <img id="title" src="images/file.gif" /> xx
</div>
```

The reason (I think) is that images aren't normal inline elements, they're "replaced" inline elements, so they behave a little differently.  What this means is that replaced elements have no actual content (they get "replaced" at render time, but the actual img itself is empty as far as the rendering engine is concerned).

Adding real content (rather than replaced content) allows the vertical-align to function.  If you place more than one element, then it works (even two img's)

The reason it works in the fiddle is that the fiddle does a lot of internal mucking about with things, and as such can sometimes have weird effects on the content.

There are a number of different workarounds for this, but all of them will require hacks which you will likely find distasteful.  You may simply be better off calculating the margin to make it centered.

BTW, "width: 100%" is redundant, block level elements (like divs) are 100% by default.

Comment: It was very insightful, to such extent that i'll grade it up so your reputation will be slightly higher BUT it still doesn't remove my confusion as to why it works on jsFiddle -> [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/AVhaZ/). I'm not tabling anything there and it works. The same code in VS2010 doesn't. Grrr...

Comment: Well i'll be {your favor profanity here}! I didn't know that but you're right, when i put "x" i'll get magic to happen... Although, i didn't make it work with two img's. Thanks for the width-comment too. Very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

normally vertical-align will not work with display block (div has default display block)
so give display table-cell or use this type of js

```
document.ready(function(){
var a = $('#div1').height();
var b = $('#img1').height();
var c = (a-b)/2;
$('#img1').css("margin-top",c);
});
```

Comment: <img> is not "display: block". You're supposed to put the vertical alignment on the aligned element, not it's parent, aren't you?

Comment: put verticle align and display table cell on parent

Comment: Consider that it works on jsFiddle: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/AVhaZ/) BUT not on my computer. I hardly think it has to do with confused styling. Also, your example seems to center the stuff relative to the screen and it relying needlessly on jQuery. This is supposed to be solvable with CSS.

Comment: what about using the javascript given above

Comment: i have updated js check it once #div1 is id of container div and #img1 is id of image which should be vertically aligned

Comment: Because (a) it's a CSS issue, (b) it'd be hiding the said issue, (c) i'm not sure that the client will have JS activated, (d) it's relating to the whole of the screen (this one can be resolved, though) and (e) it's wrong to use a work-around where there's no need for it. You like jQuery,don't you?   :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14187/discussion-between-konrad-viltersten-and-satya-teja)

Comment: @KonradViltersten - You said you are using aspx, the vast majority of aspx code requires javascript, so not having javascript enabled really isn't an option for you anyways.  Not that i'm advocating using javascript for this, just pointing out that your qualm about users having js disabled isn't really feasible anyways.

Comment: Yes. It didn't work. The only effect was, as expected, to shift the parent to the left (it was centered before) so, not to be mean, but it actually made it worse. :) In fact, if i want to quick-fix it, i can go "margin-top: 40px;" because i know how large the image will be but that's a bad programming style.